# Rails delayed job fail after close session

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I use the delayed job gem to handle my email deliveries. It is working fine in the development and I am very happy with it. However after I deployed to the server, when I use command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start
```

it will be working. I've checked the log file and database, everything is fine and I can receive the mails just as I expected. However, when I exit from the server, nothing is going to happen.

I've checked my database by using sequel pro and seen that the **delayed job has created a row in the DB and after the time in the run_at column, the row would disappear, but no mails can be received**. When I log in again, the delayed job process is still running, and the log is nothing strange, but I just cannot receive and email that I suppose to. I can't keep my self log in all the time. Without the delayed job, I can use the traditional way and it's working properly but slow. **Why the delayed job failed after I log out of the server?**

This is my delayed job setting in the config/initializers/delay_job.rb

```
require "bcrypt"

Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 5
Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = !Rails.env.test?
Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false
```

P.S. I am not sure is it anything to do with the standalone passenger as I have to use different version of rails so I have to use a standalone passenger with port 3002.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the solution.

After reading through this https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Common-problems#wiki-jobs_are_silently_removed_from_the_database

I soon realized I might miss the "require bcrypt" in the configuration file.

I use RVM and have many gemsets, but just this particular gemset has the gem bcrypt-ruby. The delayed job might use the global or default gemset after I log out the system, so I install bcrypt-ruby in all the gemsets and restart the standalone passenger and it works!.

But still, I dont really know the connection between bcrypt and the delayed job.

Comment: Wasn't there any exception in your rails log file about missing bcrypt?